# Not a duplicate, but still getting Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I'm using MySQL (ver. 8.0.32)

I have a table whose schema looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

With the following indexes:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `players`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `players_name_unique` (`name`),
ALTER TABLE `players` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `players_name_fulltext` (`name`);
```

There's already the following rows:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | jim |

When I go to run the following query:

```sql
UPDATE `players` SET `name` = '' WHERE id = 2
```

I get the following error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '??????' for key 'players.players_name_unique'

Why does MySQL think the following names are identical, or rather, not unique from each other:

I'm really stumped, I'm not sure how to remedy this? Am I doing something wrong? Should I be using a different charset?

Thank you for your help

Comment: dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/331496/not-a-duplicate-but-still-getting-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicat

Answer (score 1):

My limited understanding is that some of these characters are not in [UCA 4.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/4.0.0/allkeys-4.0.0.txt), which is implemented in the *_unicode_ci collations. All of the characters are present in [UCA 9.0.0](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/9.0.0/allkeys.txt) so you should be fine with the default utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci collation.

From the MySQL docs ([Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA) Versions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html#charset-unicode-sets-uca)):

> MySQL implements the xxx_unicode_ci collations according to the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA) described at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/. The collation uses the version-4.0.0 UCA weight keys: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/4.0.0/allkeys-4.0.0.txt. The `xxx_unicode_ci` collations have only partial support for the Unicode Collation Algorithm. Some characters are not supported, and combining marks are not fully supported. This affects languages such as Vietnamese, Yoruba, and Navajo. A combined character is considered different from the same character written with a single unicode character in string comparisons, and the two characters are considered to have a different length (for example, as returned by the [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) function or in result set metadata).
>
> Unicode collations based on UCA versions higher than 4.0.0 include the version in the collation name. Examples:
>
> - `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is based on UCA 5.2.0 weight keys (http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/5.2.0/allkeys.txt),
> - `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` is based on UCA 9.0.0 weight keys (http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/9.0.0/allkeys.txt).

| char | char name |  | UCA 4.0.0 | UCA 5.2.0 | UCA 9.0.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Negative Squared Latin Capital Letter C | [U+1F172](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F172/index.htm) | ✗ | ✗ | ✔ |
|  | Negative Squared Latin Capital Letter H | [U+1F177](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F177/index.htm) | ✗ | ✗ | ✔ |
|  | Negative Squared Latin Capital Letter A | [U+1F170](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F170/index.htm) | ✗ | ✗ | ✔ |
|  | Negative Squared Latin Capital Letter R | [U+1F181](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F181/index.htm) | ✗ | ✗ | ✔ |
|  | Negative Squared Latin Capital Letter O | [U+1F17E](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F17E/index.htm) | ✗ | ✗ | ✔ |
|  | Negative Squared Latin Capital Letter N | [U+1F17D](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F17D/index.htm) | ✗ | ✗ | ✔ |
|  | Mathematical Bold Script Capital M | [U+1D4DC](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1D4DC/index.htm) | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
|  | Mathematical Bold Script Capital U | [U+1D4E4](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1D4E4/index.htm) | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
|  | Mathematical Bold Script Capital R | [U+1D4E1](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1D4E1/index.htm) | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
|  | Mathematical Bold Script Capital D | [U+1D4D3](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1D4D3/index.htm) | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
|  | Mathematical Bold Script Capital A | [U+1D4D0](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1D4D0/index.htm) | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
|  | Mathematical Bold Script Capital H | [U+1D4D7](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1D4D7/index.htm) | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |

```sql
SET @string1 = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
SET @string2 = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

SELECT *
FROM (
    VALUES
        ROW(@string1, @string2, 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', @string1 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci = @string2 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci),
        ROW(@string1, @string2, 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci', @string1 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci = @string2 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci),
        ROW(@string1, @string2, 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', @string1 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci = @string2 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci),
        ROW(@string1, @string2, 'utf8mb4_da_0900_as_cs', @string1 COLLATE utf8mb4_da_0900_as_cs = @string2 COLLATE utf8mb4_da_0900_as_cs)
) AS x (`@string1`, `@string2`, `collation`, `equal`);
```

Output:

| @string1 | @string2 | collation | equal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | 1 |
|  |  | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci | 0 |
|  |  | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | 0 |
|  |  | utf8mb4_da_0900_as_cs | 0 |

I cannot explain why `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` sees the two strings as different, when the `Negative Squared Latin Capital Letter` characters are not present in the collation. Hopefully, someone with better understanding can explain why the characters not present in the collations are handled differently between `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.